# Thermalisation in classical thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider a volume separated in two parts by a diathermal wall. The whole volume is isolated from the outside.

In the left volume $V_1=V/2$ I put $n_1$ moles of perfect gas $1$, at pressure $P$ and temperature $T_1$.

In the right volulme $V_2=V/2$, I put $n_2$ moles of perfect gas $2$ at pressure $P$ and temperature $T_2$.

I assume the gas have the same $\gamma$.

Using the first principle, I have :

$$\Delta U_1 + \Delta U_2=n_1 c_v (T_1^f - T_1) + n_2 c_v (T_1^f - T_1) = 0$$

This equals $0$ because the full system is isolated from the outside.

Actually, both system will equilibrate towards the same temperature, and we will find : $T^f=\frac{n_1 T_1 + n_2 T_2}{n_1+n_2}$

My question is : is there a rigorous proof to say they will equilibrate toward the same temperature ?

How can we actually show that those systems won't "equilibrate" at $T_1 \neq T_2$. I know it is obvious physically but how can we show it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At equilibrium, entropy must be extremal.

So, for a virtual infinitesimal transfer of energy, $dS=0=\frac{\partial {{S}_{1}}}{\partial {{U}_{1}}}d{{U}_{1}}+\frac{\partial {{S}_{2}}}{\partial {{U}_{2}}}d{{U}_{2}}$

As the system is isolated $d{{U}_{2}}=-d{{U}_{1}}$ .

By definition of temperature $\frac{1}{{{T}_{1}}}=\frac{\partial {{S}_{1}}}{\partial {{U}_{1}}}$ and $\frac{1}{{{T}_{2}}}=\frac{\partial {{S}_{2}}}{\partial {{U}_{2}}}$ 
Finally, $dS=0=\left( \frac{1}{{{T}_{1}}}-\frac{1}{{{T}_{2}}} \right)d{{U}_{1}}$ or ${{T}_{1}}={{T}_{2}}$

For more details, you can look at Callen, Thermodynamics....p 43

Answer (score 1):

There is no proof; evolution towards thermodynamic equilibrium is a fundamental assumption in physics, a generalization of experience (experiments nad observation).

Usually, thermodynamic equilibrium requires same temperature everywhere. There are exceptions to this when gravity is involved, but those are usually negligible.

> How can we actually show that those systems won't "equilibrate" at $T_1\neq T_2$.

Again from experience: in general, if body A is at equilibrium with body B, then third body T (a thermometer)  when brought into contact with both of them, will be at equilibrium with both of them. The state of the body T can be read of as temperature.

Usually different temperatures mean heat will flow from the hotter to the colder region. Such flow means the system is not at equilibrium.

Comment: Just another question then. How do we know that the state of equal temperature is the thermodynamic equilibrium rigorously ? Does that mean we need to compute all state function and show that they don't evolve anymore when we have equality of temperatures ?

Comment: @StarBucK I've changed my answer.